# Join AD domain failed SPNEGO login failed: {Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object but has not been granted those access rights

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, samba, kerberos

I meet a problem when trying to join Active Directory domain with Samba.

The error message is

```
cli_session_creds_prepare_krb5: Doing kinit for myaccount@domain.com to access domaincontroller.hostname
cli_session_setup_spnego_send: Connect to access domaincontroller.hostname as myaccount@domain.com using SPNEGO
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_negotiate' registered
Starting GENSEC mechanism spnego
Starting GENSEC submechanism gse_krb5
Bad SMB2 signature for message
[0000] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
[0000] C1 A6 B1 DE DE D5 5D 6D   E5 27 86 90 39 7C 4E 1E   ......]m .'..9|N.
SPNEGO login failed: {Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object but has not been granted those access rights.
```

**My AD server is windows server 2012.**

I am quite sure there is something wrong configured on AD server, because same Linux host join other AD domain successuflly.

My command is "net ads join -U myaccount -k"

Here, "an object but has not been granted access rights", how can I know what object and what access permission required?

I did follow actions:

- using ldapsearch to make sure LDAP interface working fine, yes it is working fine
- join other AD domain, success
- If I do not use "-k", the error message will be:

```
    error_string             : 'Failed to set machine spn: 
    Operations error
    Do you have sufficient permissions to create machine accounts?'
```

Looks like set service principle name failed, however, I can setspn -S on AD server successfully.

So, I am guessing there is something wrong on kerberos service configuration, any suggestion on how to troubleshoot this issue is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to clarify the Windows version you’re using.  There’s no such thing as Windows Server 2010.  There is Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Sure, @GregW, thank you for pointing out this typo, my windows is 2012. Thanks!

Comment: Have you made sure an object with the same name doesn’t already exist in AD?

Comment: Thank you @Appleoddity, yes, I tried, that is another error message: 

" Failed to join domain: Failed to set machine spn: Constraint violation
Do you have sufficient permissions to create machine accounts? "

Here is Operation error (without -k in join command)

thanks.